# Angular upload - unable to view old data

Tags: javascript, angular

I am uploading a csv file and using ng2-upload for that. I am first selecting a source and then uploading the file and the data is displaying well. Now,I am changing the source from a dropdown using onItemSelect function, and have made a few parameters null, which clears old data in case of the new source. What I am unable to do is to show old data when reverting back to the old source. Old data is visible if I refresh the page.
Edit : This is the source selection part of html component :

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <ng-multiselect-dropdown
       [placeholder]="'Please Select'"
       [data]="sourceLists"
       [(ngModel)]="sourceName"
       (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
       [settings]="dropdownSettingsSource">
  </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
 </div>
```

and the Javascript part :

```
 onItemSelect(event){
   
  this.dataSource = ""
  this.merchantDataFound = null
```

Comment: Can you show some code?, it should help to understand the scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag and add it to the html tag in angular it looks like:

```
<div *ngIf="!!flag">....</>
```

So that, when changing the source you set it false, and when the data is subscribed to the source object you give true to the flag. In this way your html tag will be drawn again with the correct data inside.